# Add a subview to a UIImageView that is the view outlet of a UIViewController in IB

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, interface-builder, uiimageview

I have a UIViewController object in a .xib file.  I add a UIImageView to it, and then try to add a button as a subview of the UIImageView.  It instead replaces the UIImageView.  It works fine if both are subviews of a UIView.  What gives?  I thought this would work since UIImageView is a subclass of UIView?

Comment: This used to be an Interface Builder bug, however I don't know if it's been fixed yet.

Comment: In my opinion this isn't a bug, programatically a UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, and so can have subviews, but it's not rocket science to recognize that the image view object is somewhat simplistic in it's goal - display an image. I believe it's intended to not add subviews via IB, because it's obvious you shouldn't be doing that. Instead use a UIView and set it's backgroundImage property, or if more complex have a couple of image view's as subview of a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Apple knows.

However, look at here for a workaround:

[Apple Interface Builder: adding subview to UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415561/apple-interface-builder-adding-subview-to-uiimageview)

Answer (score 0):

A `UIImageView` is it's own object and a `UIButton` is its own object. A `UIImageView` is an outlet placeholder for an image.  If you're trying to add a background image to a button you can use the background image property or if you'd like the background to span beyond the bounds of the button you can drop a `UIView` onto IB and style that using code or subclassing `UIImageView`.

Comment: But `UIImageView` *can* have subviews.

Comment: background image property of UIView? There is no such thing.