# adding black overlay with 0.3 opacity over UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, calayer

I have a UIImageView and I wanted to add a black overlay on top of it. What is the best way of doing this without having to override drawRect? I was thinking of adding a CALayer on top of it. But unsure how to get a black CALayer with a .3 alpha.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Something like this?

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myImageView.frame.size.width, myImageView.frame.size.height / 2)];
[overlay setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.3]];
[myImageView addSubview:overlay];
```

Comment: I don't think you are supposed to add subviews to UIImageView.

Comment: This [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892770/why-cant-you-add-a-subview-to-a-uiimageview-that-is-the-view-outlet-of-a-uiview#comment21186181_4892770) says it best.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII So it's an opinion? Adding a subview to an imageview is the lesser of two evils here. It isn't officially stated anywhere that you shouldn't do this, whereas it is a blatant misuse of `colorWithPatternImage:`'s intended functionality.... And... doing this will also forfeit your ability to use the image view's built in content modes, like aspect fill/fit, etc..

Comment: I was not advocating using `colorWithPatternImage:` as a solution. I normally create a `UIView` that contains two subviews: a `UIImageView` and a `UIView` that has a the overlay. I think the fact that Apple does not allow a subview to be created in IB is enough of a hint that we should not be leading people down this path.

Comment: @HermanJ.RadtkeIII I can see your point. I'll edit this post to include more solutions to this problem later when I'm not on my phone. Thanks for bringing this up!

Comment: Hi. I believe this post has already old and cold, but in this case, I sided with @MickMacCallum. Also, many times than not, Apple does not add configurable things into Interface Builder, such as does not let us add border into a UIView. Does that means we shouldn't / couldn't add border to UIView? Only UITextField get to have border? As long as Apple does not make add subview for UIImage is a deprecated thing, then I say it's a fair game.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks to [Mick MacCallum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11217755/1371853)

**Swift 3** Version

```
let overlay: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.imageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.imageView.frame.size.height))
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.1)
cell.imageView.addSubview(overlay)
```

I have used for **Swift 2.2**

```
let overlay: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.imageView.frame.size.width, cell.imageView.frame.size.height))
overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 0/255, blue: 0/255, alpha: 0.1)
cell.imageView.addSubview(overlay)
```

Answer (score 8):

The MDT answer is correct. This is just another way to use a `CAGradientLayer` beside of `UIView` . I think it will make what you want with more graphical options.

first you should add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

to your `ViewController.m` and any place that you want to add this overlay to your `UIImage` use:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradientLayer.frame = myImageView.layer.bounds;

gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.9f alpha:0.7f].CGColor,
                        (id)[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.3f].CGColor,
                        nil];

gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                           [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5f],
                           nil];

//If you want to have a border for this layer also
gradientLayer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor;
gradientLayer.borderWidth = 1;
[myImageView.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
```

I hope this will help you make it

Comment: could you elaborate it plz?

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to MDT's answer except using CALayer properties:

```
UIView *blackOverlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: imageView.frame];
blackOverlay.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
blackOverlay.layer.opacity = 0.3f;
[self.view addSubview: blackOverlay];
```

Comment: Uh oh, you made a boo boo.  CALayer's background color is a CGColor, not a UIColor ^^;.

Answer (score 4):

Did you think about adding a `UIView` with black backgroundColor and 0.3 alpha as a subview to the image view?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5** Version:

```
func addOverlay(on view: UIView) {
    let overlay: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    overlay.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    view.addSubview(overlay)
}
```