# How to add UITextView as a subview to UIImageView on interface builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, interface-builder, uitextview

I have created a `UIImageView` and I want to add a `UITextView` as a subview beneath the image. Is there any way that I can configure this using the Interface Builder instead of hardcoding it? If not, in which part of the code should I insert the subview to and what else do I need to change?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want this label to be a subview of image view or you want it to always stick under image view no matter how tall this image is or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate with additional info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2956734/1804403

Answer (score 3):

Create View and then put both of them inside of that.

View-->

```
    |
    --->imageView
    |
    --->textView
```

Comment: It would be nice if Interface Builder allowed this, but it does appear that your are forced to create just a regular UIView container for both the image and the text view. However, you may not need to create a new container view, since it might turn out that you already have a single master view. In that case, just drag the UITextView over the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do:

```
[myImageView insertSubview:myTextView atIndex:0];
```

If you want it actually to be "part of" the UIImageView I don't think you can do it in Interface Builder.  But this is a normal method of extending UIKit views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it in Interface Builder - see the image

[image]

To get this view, at the bottom there is an `<` arrow image. Click to get this. After that its drag your UI element underneath any other element to add that element as a `subview` of that UI element...

Of course you can do this in code by simply writing `[someView addSubView:newView];`

Comment: You cannot drag anything under a UIImageView