# add subview to UIImageView via interface builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiimageview

Is such thing possible? I have my UIScrollView created via IB and I wanted it as a subview of a UIImgeView I have, created in IB as well. If it is possible how do I do so?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to do it the other way around? (i.e. add the image view as a subview of the scroll view?)

Comment: what is the difficulty you are facing??

Comment: possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2956734/1804403

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer `NO`. The workarounds depend on what's more important to you

#### 1. Creating the `UIImageView` subview hierarchy in the xib is most important

Start with a `UIView` but change it's class to `UIImageView`

[image]

then set the image in code

```
self.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
```

#### 2. Setting the image in the xib is most important

Then do as you have been doing and add the subviews in code

```
[self.myImageView addSubview:someSubView];
```

#### 3. You want the imageView and the other view to move and scale in unison

Then place them in a container `UIView` that is the same size as the `UIImageView`

[image]

Here you can see a `container` `UIView` that holds the `UIImageView` and another subview

Answer (score 0):

If you can't drag it into the UIImageView then I do not think it is possible,and an imageViews purpose is not meant to hold subviews. But it is just as easy to add it in code

```
[imageView addSubview:subView];
```