# Draw on UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a following image on uiimageview and i want to draw a small dot on that image can somebody tell me how i can do that

[image]

i want to create a radar kind a view so i need to easily add a small circle and remove it after a some time i have try drawing on `uiimage` view but it always create a new `uiimage` and apply it to `uiimageview` is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Add another UIImageView to current imageView.

Comment: can we add a uiimageview on exact point ?

Comment: Of course you can. Just set its center property or change the frame directly (x and y coordinates).

Comment: if you can give me some sample code it will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
UIImageView *smallCircle = //alloc init assign your image

[smallCircle setCenter: CGPointMake (x value, y value)]

[bigCircleImageView.superview addSubview: smallCircle];
[bigCircleImageView.superview bringSubviewToFront: smallCircle];
```

Comment: how can i add this on my current imageview i try to add this on my imageview but it dosent show this is what i do  UIImage *myScreenShot = [UIImage imageNamed:@"point.png"];
    
   
    UIImageView *smallCircle =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myScreenShot];
    
    [smallCircle setCenter: CGPointMake (self.imageView.frame.origin.x,self.imageView.frame.origin.y)];

Comment: You require to add this as subview along with big circle image. And then bring this view on top.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly you are unable to add subviews to UIImageView see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415561/apple-interface-builder-adding-subview-to-uiimageview)
You could add both the UIImageViews to an empty view and position them correctly though.