# Customize image in iOS and save to gallery

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, customization

Basically I want to add an `UIView` on image and that image save to gallery.
`UIView` contains some text and image, and that `UIView` add on image.

Comment: not getting question!

Comment: you mean that you want to save image on gallery having a combination of  text and image right?

Comment: combination of capture uiview and image

Comment: you have to use uiimageview not uiimage

Comment: you can't add look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415561/apple-interface-builder-adding-subview-to-uiimageview

Answer (score -1):

Add (as subviews) all UI objects that you want to capture to one `UIView`, then make a screenshot of that view using the following piece of code:

```
CGRect rect = [captureView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Then you can save the obtained UIImage to gallery:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(capturedImage, nil, nil, nil);
```