# Xcode 8/ Swift 3 - How can I lock button constraints to a pinch to zoom image so they zoom in and out with the image?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, swift3

I have a view controller with a scroll view, followed by a map-like image inside the view. On top of the map image I have 16 different pin buttons pointing to different parts on a map image. As of now I can zoom in and out of the map but the 16 buttons do not follow and get scattered. How can I attach or lock the buttons onto the map image so they zoom in and out with the map. As of now inside my map view controller I have this: (thanks in advance for an answer!)

```
import UIKit

class MapppViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var mapImageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.mainScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
    self.mainScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView ) -> UIView?
{
    return self.mapImageView
```

Comment: "On top of the map image" But they are not subviews? What are they? Show how the pin buttons get there.

Comment: I'm new to xcode so i'm not sure what you mean? Here is a pic of what I have: http://i68.tinypic.com/2lxwoeo.png

Comment: Right, those are not subviews of the map image view. If you make them subviews, they will remain stationary with respect to the map as it zooms (though they will, by default, grow / shrink as the map is zoomed; however, you can change that).

Comment: And also here is a gif of what my problem is an how i can't figure out how to lock the buttons onto the map to move when zoomed in: https://gifyu.com/image/SF0W

Comment: if it's as simple as you say with the "subviews" how would i go about doing this? do you have a link or video on how to do it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Drag the buttons onto the image view. Right now they are hovering in _front_ of the image view but they are not _part_ of the image view. If they are subviews, they are part of it and dependent on it. If you don't know what subviews are, you might want to read my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_subview_and_superview

Comment: I tried that.. Take a look here: https://gifyu.com/image/SFCr Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @matt via above...

Comment: Yeah, Interface Builder (Xcode) makes this really hard. They don't want you make anything a subview of an image view. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415561/apple-interface-builder-adding-subview-to-uiimageview. Sorry about that. Either you'd have to configure this in code, or you'd use a common "container view" as I do in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a sketchy way, I presume this is the sort of thing you're after:

[image]

You can achieve that either by making the buttons subviews of the image view or (as I did here) by making the buttons and the image view subviews of a "container view" that serves no other purpose except to be the zoomable subview of the scroll view.

Here's my view hierarchy:

[image]

Here's the only code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sv: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sv.minimumZoomScale = 1
        self.sv.maximumZoomScale = 2
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return scrollView.viewWithTag(999) // the container view
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @matt This was exactly what I was looking for and could not find it anywhere on the internet. I really appreciate your help on this! Your awesome!

Comment: Hey @matt another question for you. After doing the above what is the best way to constraint the buttons so that on different devices the buttons stay locked in position on the map? Upon zooming in and out the device I made it on (iPhone 7) it works great but on others I can't figure out how to add constraints that become blue. I've looked on google but every page/tutorial showing constraints does not have the type of hierarchy/set up I have. Thanks in advance. I'm new to this...

Comment: Simplest is _no_ constraints. As long as the map is the same size on every device, the buttons will be in the right place. Otherwise, you'd have to work out the button top/left based on a _percentage_ of the image size (`multiplier`) in order to get them to be in same spot of the map itself.

Comment: Hey  @matt on your example of the hierarchy above what would you put constraints on to hold the map in place? And what would the constraints be? I feel like I've tried every type of constraint but can't get it to work

Comment: i've gotten up to this far with the map app i'm doing. Could you help me out? I got the buttons on my map to work on every device besides an ipad. The buttons just scatter and aren't in the correct position. Heres a gif of the problem. (My computer is a bit slow so give it time to load) https://gifyu.com/image/SYrt